# Render is not a function facebook ads

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-ads-api

I am making React Native expo app and I started adding Facebook ads to my app. I got the id then I have installed `expo-ads-facebook` package, but when I start adding the banner it give me an error:

> r.render is not a function

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FacebookAds } from 'expo'

class AdScreen extends React.Component {
  ViewWithBanner(props) {
    return (
      <FacebookAds.BannerAd
        placementId="2272791379702600_2272803043034767"
        type="standard"
        onPress={() => console.log('click')}
        onError={error => console.log('error', error)}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default createStackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: AdScreen }
}, 
{initialRouteName: 'Main'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There´s no render function, but you do need one if using a class component with JSX. For example:

```
class AdScreen extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <FacebookAds.BannerAd
                placementId="2272791379702600_2272803043034767"
                type="standard"
                onPress={() => console.log('click')}
                onError={error => console.log('error', error)}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can follow the docs to create a stateless functional component: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook-ads/

Side Note: Judging from your imports, it appears that you are using an outdated version of expo. I would recommend to upgrade to the latest one for a new project.

Comment: i am using outdated version because another version does not support this: import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook'; It is says that they can not get data

Comment: did you follow everything in the docs, including the "Development vs Production" section?

Comment: i have put it and it gave me error: Unable to resolve "@unimodules/core" from "node_modules/expo-ads-facebook/build/withNativeAd.js"

Comment: that´s an entirely different set of problems, you should google for that error and maybe create another thread if you cannot solve it. it was just a side note that it´s usually better to use the latest version. did my answer solve the main problem of your question? you basically copy/pasted the stateless functional component from the expo docs into a class component.